# Xamarin Parse.com caching or local storage

Tags: android, caching, parse-platform, xamarin, local-storage

I have an app built in Xamarin (Android) that extensively uses Parse as the backend. When i say extensively i mean the app has to query Parse almost continuously as it scans for iBeacons.

It works perfectly well as is, but the problem is scalability in terms of the number of consecutive requests to Parse per second. In other words the number of requests will get ridiculous as soon as there are more than a hundred or so app users.

I need to be able to store the data from Parse locally. As far as i'm aware though, Parse doesn't support local storage via the .Net API, not do they provide caching for .Net.

Can anybody recommend what the best alternative is here? My Parse tables contain pointers etc. so i need to be able to replicate this locally or somehow cache the data.

Thanks.

Comment: I use native android, but using local datastore to sort a list by position every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Parse .NET APIs do not support [Local Datastore](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore) like in android, until they support it, you can either use any .NET generic data caching libraries, or just convert your parse data to JSON and save/serialize it into a local file.

something [like akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) may satisfy your requirements.